# Entity Framework 2 different tables retrieve data as single entity

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

We have 2 exactly same tables in our database. One is an archive of the other.

How can I retrieve the data from the archive table without changing the entity type using Entity Framework and Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you map your tables to EF entities you can automatically create classes for the entities. Why do you want to avoid creating separate classes for different tables? If you want a common contract for the two so that you can pass them to other functions that perform the same operations on both, I would add an interface to the generated entities instead. That way you can use the auto generated entities but still be able to treat them as "one"

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a `.Select(x=>new SomeTypeOfObject{Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop2 = x.Prop2})`